# Why is it useful to make a const function?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, constants

why is it so useful to make a function const if you only can read variables but not write(class variable)?

Comment: You can write variables. You just can't write class variables.

Comment: I meant that but i forgot to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass something else a const pointer or const reference to an instance of your class then it can only call the class's const methods (if any).

Obviously, if you never bother with const-correctness with your types then you can ignore this.

I suppose it may also help the compiler optimize things in certain situations, although I am doubtful and, even if it did help, allowing that small improvement (if any) to dictate how you wrote your code would be a case of premature optimization in most situations.

Comment: wrt optimization: a compiler could make aggressive optimizations based on const correctness, particularly when the method body is not visible to the translation. it may be as useful to the compiler as the restrict keyword (which can generate code more than 10x faster because it doesn't have to load and store every address that could possibly change). iow, if you enable optimizations and follow const-correctness, the compiler may see a function as const and assume the value it holds based on an object's data has not changed, and therefore will not need to be reread.

Comment: I find it sad that it always seems to be performance that C++ people obsess over when software challenges are mostly about correctness.

Answer (score 3):

So that you do not "accidentally" modify one of the class variables. It is just a safety measure.

(If you use the const keyword after a function that *does* modify any data member of the class - either directly or through another function call - you will get a compilation error).

Comment: Note that it's not *much* of a safety measure; you can always get around it with casting.

Comment: @dan04: That's a misconception.  Use of `const_cast` to modify objects is legal only under very rare circumstances, pretty much only where the user of `const_cast` added the `const` modifier in the first place, to a pointer or reference that wasn't originally `const`.

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that `const` is a virus. That means that if part of the code is const-correct, then the rest of the code won't interoperate with that part.

If you ignore const-correctness, chances of your classes working hand-in-hand with other libraries (beginning with the standard library) are slim.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct X
{
    int n;
    bool operator< (X b)
    { 
        return n < b.n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> vec;
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

With codepad.org

```
In function 'const _Tp& std::__median(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = X]':
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2642:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, __gnu_norm::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_debug_def::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, _Size = int]'
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2713:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<X*, __gnu_norm::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >, __gnu_debug_def::vector<X, std::allocator<X> > >]'
t.cpp:17:   instantiated from here
Line 90: error: no match for 'operator<' in '__a < __b'
```

A stdlib compatible comparison operator must make a promise that arguments are not modified. If objects actually were to change while they are compared, an attempt to sort them would be rather futile.

Another example: you won't be able to pass arguments by const reference which is the conventional way of passing large objects. Instead you'd have to pass arguments by modifiable references. Now you won't be able to pass temporaries of any kind to your functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a const object, it only allows const member functions to operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

The more of the contract between caller and callee you can express in code instead of documentation, the more help the compiler can give you with complying with that contract (from both ends).  const-ness of the implicit `this` pointer is an important part of that as is const-ness of all other parameter referents. (of course top-level constness of pass-by-value parameters is not part of the contract)

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that you can get the compiler to enforce where state can be modified. For example if you make a class with private data and all its methods, except, say, the constructor, are const, then you have an immutable data type.  The benefit of this is not one of performance, but one of semantics.